# "Expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '->' token

Tags: c

So here's the code from the start to the lines my errors appear. I checked more than once every pointer relation and sintax rules, but for the last three lines the complier says:

```
"Expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '->' token
```

What's wrong/missing?

Code:

```
typedef char labeltype;

typedef struct celltag{
labeltype label;
struct celltag* leftchild;
struct celltag* rightchild;
}celltype;

typedef celltype* BiTree;
typedef celltype* node;

node LAMBDA;
LAMBDA->label='A';
LAMBDA->leftchild=NULL;
LAMBDA->rightchild=NULL;
```

Comment: Where is this code ? Is it **all** within a function ? If not, what is/is-not where? A [mcve] is required for us to help. Otherwise all we're doing is throwing out guesses, which makes for *terrible* answers. And fyi, this code dereferences an indeterminate pointer, so after fixing your compile issue you have *undefined behavior* on your horizon.

Comment: I recommend not hiding pointers in a typedef.  It usually leads to bad things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have any functions in your code, and Instructions can only appear in functions.

The following lines are Instructions, which must be in a function:

```
LAMBDA->label='A';
LAMBDA->leftchild=NULL;
LAMBDA->rightchild=NULL;
```

---

I recommend putting these instructions into a main function:

```
typedef char labeltype;

typedef struct celltag{
labeltype label;
struct celltag* leftchild;
struct celltag* rightchild;
}celltype;

typedef celltype* BiTree;
typedef celltype* node;

int main(void)   /* This is where a function starts */
{
    node LAMBDA;

    printf("Program Start\n");
    LAMBDA->label='A';
    LAMBDA->leftchild=NULL;
    LAMBDA->rightchild=NULL;
    printf("Program End\n");
    return 0;
}    /* This is the end of the function */
```

Comment: This does solve the problem in the question, but I think it still has the issue of dereferencing an uninitialized pointer.

Answer (score 2):

In C language all executable code is written *inside functions*. You can't just write statements in the middle of the file.

At file level in C you can only write declarations. Everything in your code are declarations, until you get to the last three lines. The last three lines are not declarations. You can't write them at file level.

Comment: Will it be enough to declare just `node LAMBDA;` where it is now, so I can use it in other functions, but add the other information to LAMBDA when I get to writing the `main()` function?

Comment: @Lena: It will be enough to stop the compiler from complaining. Whether it is enough to make the code work as intended is something only you can know. In any case, your `LAMBDA` is a *pointer*. It points to nowhere initially. You can't access data fields through a pointer that points to nowhere. For example, the current version of abelenky's code is broken for this very reason.